# How to match only the first letter of the string

Tags: php

I want to match only the first letter of the string i.e 'bot'.
For ex: 
It should run a function if user types `"bot hi"` and should not work if they type `"hi bot there"`

```
if(preg_match('[bot ]', strtolower($message))) {
    $msg = str_replace('bot ', '', $message);
    //Some message response
}
```

the above code works even if I type `"hi bot there"`

Comment: you want to match the letter "b" ?

Comment: what if a user typed just *"bo"*? The replacement `str_replace('bot ', '', $message)` requires to type at least `bot `. Make your question to be more clear

Comment: Besides, what if user typed `Bot ..`, should it match?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest  the code should work only if user types bot hi. and I don't want the word 'bot' while comparing with bot response string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the ^ for tell at begin of the string

```
  if ( preg_match("/^bot (.*)/i", $message) ) {

   $msg = str_replace('bot ', '', $message);
    //Some message response
 }
```

Comment: it would be enough to use `if (preg_match("/^bot (.*)/i", strtolower($message))) { ...`. No need to compare with `0`

Comment: Thanks mate this works :) could you explain it clearly?

Comment: Also you don't need to use `strtolower()` when you used regex `i` flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this with `strpos()` :

```
    $str = "bot hi";
    if (0 === strpos($str, 'bot')) {
       echo("str starts with bot");
   else{
       echo("str does not starts with bot");
       }
    }
```